# Query for create and update fields into two tables joined with pivot table (many to many) with laravel query builder or mysql

Tags: mysql, crud, laravel-9, laravel-query-builder

I have three tables

1.PURCHASE TABLE

| id | Country | Medicine | Quantity | Purchase date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Canada | Aspirin | 9 | 26/01/2022 14:16:59 |
| 1 | Canada | VitaminD | 10 | 19/07/2021 14:16:59 |
| 2 | Usa | Calcium | 4 | 19/06/2021 14:16:59 |
| 3 | Canada | VitaminC | 8 | 06/08/2022 14:16:59 |
| 4 | Argentina | Calcium | 10 | 05/12/2021 14:16:59 |

2.PRICES TABLE

| id | Country | Year | Medicine | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | USA | 2020 | Aspirin | 14 |
| 1 | Canada | 2020 | Aspirin | 18 |
| 2 | Mexico | 2020 | Aspirin | 10 |
| 3 | Brasil | 2020 | Aspirin | 11 |
| 4 | Argentina | 2021 | Aspirin | 18 |

3. PRICE_PURCHASE TABLE (PIVOT TABLE)

| price_id | purchase_id |
| --- | --- |

How can I create and update the fields in both using laravel query builder or mysql ?

Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attach` method to insert into the pivot table. This method accept an array, if you want a multiple insert.

Also, you can use `detach` to remove a record from the pivot table.

I think, if you want to insert or update the main tables you have to do it directly, without pivot table.

Here are the links from docs:

[Attaching - Detaching](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#attaching-detaching)

This method is using Eloquent ORM. If you want to use you should use `subqueries` or `JOIN` to 'connect' pivot table with the main tables.